# JSch to use Unix Remote Server Environment Variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, jsch

I'm using JSch to connect my java to a remote unix server. The next step would be to run a shell script (.sh) which makes use of some internal environment variables.

On executing the shell script directly from terminal works fine, but calling it from a java program via JSch does not recognize these variables. How do I work around this. Less experienced on Java. Posting the sample code-

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "server", 22);
    UserInfo ui = new SftpUserInfo();
    session.setUserInfo(ui);
    session.setPassword("mypass");
    session.connect();

    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

    InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();


    channelExec.setCommand("sh /filePath/myShellScript.sh");
    channelExec.connect();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

PS: The environment variables are set at ".profile" in users root folder (/home/username/)

Thanks,

Arya

Comment: did u find any solutions for this problem?

Comment: @Neron did u find any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I execute a jar stored on my server using JSch. That jar uses the class ProcessBuilder that allows modifying environment variables.  For example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh /filePath/myShellScript.sh");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("profile","/home/username/");
```